# Table doesn't exist error in Django when using two databases

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project where i'm using two Databases. On a view, i have the following query:

```
data = get_object_or_404(MyModel, ticker=ticker).using('second')
```

This query will raise the following error:

```
(1146, "Table 'db.myapp_mymodel' doesn't exist")
```

Which happens because Django is looking for the table in the **first** database, while the table is in the **second** database. Why does this happen even when i used `using()` and when in my model it's specified that the table is located on my second database? How can i fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the [**`.using(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#using) to the queryset, *not* after the [**`get_object_or_404(…)`**[Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404), since then it is too late: the query is then already done. So:

```
data = get_object_or_404(MyModel.objects.using('second'), ticker=ticker)
```